# Getting image coords relative to original image after image is rotated 90, 180, or 270 degrees

Tags: javascript, image, rotation, coordinates

I know there is probably a simple mathematical solution for this, but I just havent been able to get it (w/o doing some long drawn out process).

Lets say I have a landscape image thats 1200px width x 800px height....and then the image is rotated clockwise either 90, 180, or 270 degrees.

If a point (coordinate) is selected on the rotated image, how do I determine what the coordinate would be on the original non-rotated image?

As an easy example: if the above image is rotated 180 degrees, and then a coord is set at 100, 100 (top left corner)....the same coord would be 1100, 700 (bottom right) on the non-rotated image.

Syntax wise, Im trying to calculate this in Javascript

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Positing what you've tried and why it doesn't seem to work (and error message, strange output) is an important part of asking a question on S.O.

Comment: What I tried does work. But it's a sloppy if (90).... else if (180)....else if (270)... piece of bloat. Im just looking for a much more clean/efficient option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mathematically formal way to do this is with a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Common_rotations)

For example for anti-clockwise 90 degree rotation, the rotation matrix would be:

```
R(90) = [0 -1]
        [1  0]
```

And the matrix multiplication formula would be:

```
[x90] = [0 -1][x]
[y90]   [1  0][y]
```

Using [matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) to expand this out into standard notation:

```
x90 = -y;
y90 =  x;
```

Note that this rotates around the origin [0, 0], so you will have to normalize to get all +ve coordinates.
Written in javascript, this would be something like:

```
x90 = ymax - y;
y90 = x;
```

Here [x,y] are the original coordinates, [x90, y90] are the rotated coordinates and [xmax, ymax] are the width and height of the *original* image.

For 180 degrees the rotation matrix is:

```
R(180) = [-1  0]
         [ 0 -1]
```

Translating to javascript, with normalization:

```
x180 = xmax - x;
y180 = ymax - y;
```

For anti-clockwise 270 degrees the rotation matrix is:

```
R(270) = [ 0 1]
         [-1 0]
```

Translating to javascript, with normalization:

```
x270 = y;
y270 = xmax - x;
```

Comment: Thanks! I feel stupid that it was this easy. But shouldnt x90 = ymax - x?

Comment: I guess I should have clarified that Im basing this off 0,0 being the top left corner.

Comment: If I take a 1200x800 image and rotate it 90 degrees CW, then select the coord 100px from the top right corner (700,100), the rotated/original coords should be 100, 100. x90 = ymax - y; (800 - 100 = 700).

Answer (score 0):

This [similar question and answer on MathOverflow](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122848/calculated-rotated-point-coordinate-is-my-solution-correct) should be what you want.

tl;dr:

```
x' = x*cos(θ) - y*sin(θ)
y' = x*sin(θ) + y*cos(θ)
```

where `{x,y}` is your original point, `θ` the rotation angle, and `{x',y'}` the new point.

Comment: Thanks!, but how could this work if the image dimensions (w & h) arent included? The 180 degree result for 100,100 would be different if the image was 640x480 (540,380) vs 1200x800 (1100,700).